# Best Azure Time Series Insights alternative

Tags: database, iot, azure

For a new project I am looking for a way to store data in Azure. Since the data is data coming from IoT devices, my thoughts jumped to a Time Series Database and looking at the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/data-store-overview#time-series-databases) that seems to match quite nicely.

So following that link and going to the documentation we end at this [page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/overview-what-is-tsi)

However there is a note attached to the documentation.

> The Time Series Insights (TSI) service will no longer be supported after March 2025. Consider migrating existing TSI environments to alternative solutions as soon as possible. For more information on the deprecation and migration, visit our [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/migration-to-adx).

Here it seems that Microsoft recommends to switch to Azure Data Explorer. However by looking at its pricing and specs it seems to be a bit overpowered for my goal.

The current specification is that I will have 50.000 devices that will send their data to Azure about 1x/day. Once they have transferred their data, a second query will be made to request new settings (if any). The data needs to be stored for about 2 years, then it can be removed.

My main question is: What is the best (and cheapest) way to store this data?